# Using Validation Set in Transfer Learning for Feature Extractor Preprocessor

Tags: keras, image-classification, feature-extraction, transfer-learning

I have a set of images of products. I am using transfer learning for images feature extraction in this way :

1. I load a model (res-net, vgg)
2. I add 2 dense layers, first one will be my features and the next one is a softmax layer for classification
3. I freeze all the model's layer and I train the neural network for a classification
4. I get my features by returning the result of the before last layer

My question is whether to use a validation set in the training, or not.

Comment: Why do you think you should not use the validation set?

Comment: Because without it I cannot use early stopping, and so I cannot know if the neural network is just overfitting over the data

Comment: Yeah, exactly my point. So, you answered your own question right? But I wanted to know that why do you think you should "not" use the validation set?

Comment: because at the end of the day, I'm interested in getting the features of all the images